# Redirect request to a second URL if an error is encountered on first in NGINX

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, redirect

I'm new to NGINX and I'm trying to figure out whether I need a proxy or a reverse proxy. Here's the requirement:

Create a proxy that will hit websiteA, if no error is encounter (node is not down but it returns an error) return the result otherwise forward the request to websiteB and return the result.

I already have NGINX running but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use nginx as a load ballancer, which will evaluate the health of the nodes you have behind it. And if one is considered unreachable, stop routing traffic to it.

Check [NGINX HTTP Health Checks](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-health-check/) and [TCP Health Checks](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-health-check/)

You could still use nginx as a web server, via a separate config

Comment: Hi Ron, websiteA should be reachable and should return a message or code and base on that code either return the result or forward the request to websiteB.

Comment: Well, you can always do this on application level, where your code can try and send a request to websiteA, and wait for a timely response, and if it errors out, try websiteB

Comment: Yes. But there's a reason why we needed a proxy. Thanks.